# Проблема с наложением текста PIL

Tags: python

имею такой код:

```
code
import urllib.request
from PIL  import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os

url = 'https://sun3-12.userapi.com/c855732/v855732717/17f22f/ZXQOfetBkjQ.jpg?ava=1'
font_path = 'G:\WORK\\18177.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path)

def downloadImg(url,path):
    img = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    out = open(path, "wb")
    out.write(img)
    out.close()

downloadImg(url,'output.png')

def createElipse(path):
    im = Image.open(path)
    size = (400, 400)  # размер итогового портрета

    # маска
    mask = Image.new('L', size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
    draw.ellipse((0, 0) + size, fill=255)

    im = im.resize(size)

    output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
    output.putalpha(mask)
    output.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    output.save(path)
    output.close()

createElipse('output.png')

def createStatePng(ava):
    fi = Image.open(ava)
    im = Image.open(os.getcwd()+'\\zadatok.png')
    im.paste(fi,(200,100),fi) 
    im.text((300,300),'Этот текст будет наложен на твоё изображение :d',(255,0,0),font)
    im.save("autist.png")
    im.close()

createStatePng('output.png')
code
```

На строчке с добавлением текста на изображения скрипт прекращает работу с ошибкой:

```
File "G:\WORK\downloadPNG.py", line 40, in createStatePng
    im.text((300,300),'Этот текст будет наложен на твоё изображение :d',(255,0,0),font):d',(255,0,0),font)
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Непонятен текст ошибки? Неясно, что делать? В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Я понял текст ошибки, но мне кажется, что ошибка какая-то нелогичная. Во первых, изображение там было не JPEG, а PNG.
Почему я не могу наложить текст на картинку?

Comment: Не можете наложить текст на картинку, потому что у объекта JpegImageFile нет свойства text. Написано же. А точно картинка в формате png? Не расширение, а именно само изображение? У PngImageFileтоже текста не, кстати.

Comment: попробуйте конвертировать в ImageDraw.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Спасибо, смог )

Comment: __Отлично! :)_ _

Comment: Качаете `.../ZXQOfetBkjQ.jpg` сохраняете в файл с расширением `.png`, но внутри остался файл jpg, поэтому и JpegImageFile

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы добавить текст на фотографию(Картинку) нужно

```
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
```

Далее нужно обозначить где находится ваша картинка и указать, что мы будем на ней рисовать

```
img = Image.open("Images/test.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
```

Далее используем ImageFont.truetype("путь к шрифту", размер) для определения шрифта, который мы добавим на фото

```
# font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Images/18930.ttf", 60)
```

Далее объединяем все вместе и сохраняем

```
# draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
draw.text((100, 100),"Простой пример текста",(255,255,255),font=font)
img.save('Images/test_with_text.jpg')
```

Исходное изображение[image: Простой голубой фон]
Изображение после обработки кодом который написан сверху[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственный минус который имеется (Лично я считаю его значительным), так это Качество вставляемого текста. Возможно его можно изменить, но я об этом не знаю.